# How do I solve this Diophantine equation?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

How do I solve this Diophantine equation, $a^{2n}+b^2=c^{2n}$, where $n$ is any postive integer $>1$ & $a,b,c\ne0$?

I tried it by applying the Pythagorean triplets generating formula, but unable to find any integer solutions & nor I'm able to prove that there are no integer solutions except $a,b,c=0$. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: Why do you think that the equation has non-trivial solution? Did you find any?

Comment: According to https://oeis.org/A147857 there are no solutions when $n=2$ (but no proof is given).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365968/understanding-diophantine-equation-proof-w-link for the case $n=2$, also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153546/solving-x4-y4-z2 and see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344017/any-solution-in-positive-integers-of-the-equation-y3-x3-z2-other-than for $n=3/2$ (I know...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the links. Now, at least I know that for the case $n=2$, there are no solutions. Thanks again.

Comment: We only need to consider the case where $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k>1$ be a positive integer, and let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive integers such that
$$a^{2k}+b^2=c^{2k}.\tag{0}$$
Let $d:=\gcd(a,c)$ so that $d^{2n}$ divides $a^{2k}$ and $c^{2k}$, and hence also $b^2$. Then $d^k$ divides $b$ and so $(a,b,c)=(dA,d^kB,dC)$ for some positive integers $A$, $B$ and $C$ with $\gcd(A,C)=1$. It follows that also $\gcd(A,B)=\gcd(B,C)=1$, and it is easily verified that
$$A^{2k}+B^2=C^{2k}.$$
So without loss of generality $a$, $b$ and $c$ are pairwise coprime. Then $(a^k,b,c^k)$ forms a primitive Pythagorean triple, and so either
$$a^k=m^2-n^2,\qquad b=2mn,\qquad c^k=m^2+n^2,$$
or
$$a^k=2mn,\qquad b=m^2-n^2,\qquad c^k=m^2+n^2,$$
for some coprime positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $mn$ even. In the first case we see that
$$a^k+c^k=(m^2-n^2)+(m^2+n^2)=2m^2.$$
But by the main theorem of [this article](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/18.Merel/paper.pdf)  such a solution does not exist for $k\geq3$. In the second case we see that
$$a^k+c^k=(2mn)+(m^2+n^2)=(m+n)^2.$$
Again by the main theorem of that article such a solution does not exist for $k\geq4$. So either $k=2$ or $k=3$.

For $k=2$ it is a classical result of Fermat that the Diophantine equation
$$x^4-y^4=z^2,$$
has no nontrivial integral solutions. See also this question on math.stackexchange:
[Solving $x^4-y^4=z^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153546/solving-x4-y4-z2) .
This leaves only the case $k=3$, for which I do not see a slick solution.

**Proposition:** The Diophantine equation $x^6-y^6=z^2$ has no primitive integral solutions with $y\neq0$ even.

*Proof.* Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be pairwise coprime integers such that $x^6-y^6=z^2$, with $y$ even and $|y|>0$ minimal. Then $(u,v,w)=(x^2,-y^2,z)$ satisfies
$$u^3+v^3=w^2,$$
and it is a classical result by Euler that any primitive solution is of one of the following three forms:
\begin{align}
(1)&\begin{cases}
u&=s(s+2t)(s^2-2st+4t^2)\\
v&=-4t(s-t)(s^2+st+t^2)\\
w&=\pm(s^2-2st-2t^2)(s^4+2s^3t+6s^2t^2-4st^3 + 4t^4)
\end{cases}
& 2\nmid s,\ 3\nmid(s-t),\\
\\
(2)&\begin{cases}
u&=s^4-4s^3t-6s^2t^2-4st^3 + t^4\\
v&=2(s^4+2s^3t+2st^3+t^4)\\
w&=3(s-t)(s+t)(s^4+2s^3t+6s^2t^2+2st^3+t^4)
\end{cases}
&2\nmid(s-t),\ 3\nmid(s-t),\\
\\
(3)&\begin{cases}
u&=-3s^4 + 6s^2t^2 + t^4\\
v&=3s^4+6s^2t^2-t^4\\
w&=6st(3s^4+t^4)
\end{cases}
&2\nmid(s-t),\ 3\nmid t,
\end{align}
after swapping $u$ and $v$ if necessary. In all three cases $s$ and $t$ are coprime integers. For a proof, see $\S 14.3.1$ of Henri's Cohen's [Number Theory, Vol II,
Analytic and Modern Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387498931).

Because $w=z$ is odd the solution $(u,v,w)=(x^2,-y^2,z)$ cannot be of the form $(3)$. It cannot be of the form $(2)$ because $-y^2\equiv0\pmod{4}$, whereas $u\equiv1\pmod{4}$ and $v\equiv2\pmod{4}$. It folows that it is of the form $(1)$, and so
\begin{eqnarray}
x^2&=&s(s+2t)(s^2-2st+4t^4)&=&s(s^3+8t^3),\\
y^2&=&4t(s-t)(s^2+st+t^2)&=&4t(s^3-t^3)
\end{eqnarray}
for two coprime integers $s$ and $t$ with $s$ odd and $3\nmid(s-t)$. The factors in each product are pairwise coprime, and hence they are all perfect squares, say
$$s=S^2,\qquad t=T^2,\qquad s+2t=q^2,\qquad s^3-t^3=p^2,$$
for some integers $S$, $T$ , $p$ and $q$, not necessarily prime. Reducing mod $4$ shows that $t$ is even, and so we find
$$S^6-T^6=p^2,$$
with $S$, $T$ and $p$ pairwise coprime and $T$ even, where clearly $|S|<|x|$ and $|T|<|y|$. This contradicts the minimality of $|y|$, and so we conclude that there does not exist any primitive solution with $y\neq0$ even.$\qquad\square$

Together this finally shows that equation $(0)$ does not have any solutions in positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ for any integer $k>1$.